# display price filter widget on category page woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I am trying to show price filter and layered widget on all pages of wordpress.
I know its woocommerc rule but i want it badly. 
Is it possible to create any hooks for it? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options.

1) Display the price filter via shortcode for all the site.
2) Set do_action('custom_hook_name'); in the header,footer or sidebar wherever you want to display and then add_filter('custom_hook_name','your_function_name'); inside the functions.php

Also if you can describe which price filter you want to display will help the best.

Comment: I am using woocommerce default price filter. I am not much familiar with woocommerce can you write down shortcode for price filter or hooks please?